# Move window when typing in XFCE

Tags: arch-linux, xfce

i use **xfce desktop** on **Archlinux**.

Sometimes when I'm typing or coding in a program environment, the mouse pointer changes to move automatically and Keyboard typing stop Until i click somewhere.

After one click the mouse pointer releases and I can type...

This is similar to that I right-clicked on windows title and selected Move

This is a nerve-wracking problem I have not experienced in GNOME.

how can i fix this ???

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a shortcut that you accidentally trigger from time to time. Shortcut can be set in any number of ways, but first check your keyboard shortcuts in the Window Manager settings and see if anything there may cause the situation; in particular, see if you have a shortcut for "Move window" that may be typed accidentally.

Here's further descriptions that may be of help:

- https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfwm4/getting-started
- https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/customize-keyboard-shortcuts-on-the-xfce4/